# Centering texts inside div using Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I am trying to split the div "Info" into three sections to evenly divide the sections. I think I did that correctly to begin, but I am having issues centering the titles (Address, Hours, Contact) from their own divs. The example below is how I'm trying to make it look. Thank you for your time.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E53eW.jpg)

```css
.info{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
      <div class="left-info">
        <div class="address-title">
          Address
        </div>
        <div class="address">
          1111 Some Words, Tampa, FL 33647, United States
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="middle-info">
        <div class="hours-title">
          Hours
        </div>
        <div class="hours">
          Mon-Fri
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-info">
        <div class="contact-title">
          Contact
        </div>
        <div class="contact">
          111-111-1111
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: simply put text-align: center; in the .info

Comment: I literally tried every option besides that one, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. I've given `width: 33%` to each div inside `.info` in order to divide the entire width into three equal width. In addition, gave `text-align: center` to individual divs.

```css
.info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-info,
.right-info,
.middle-info {
 width: 33%;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="left-info">
    <div class="address-title">
      Address
    </div>
    <div class="address">
      1111 Some Words, Tampa, FL 33647, United States
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle-info">
    <div class="hours-title">
      Hours
    </div>
    <div class="hours">
      Mon-Fri
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-info">
    <div class="contact-title">
      Contact
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
      111-111-1111
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps you.